# How to manipulate JSON object to remove root key within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json url that returns data in the format

```
{
  "photos" : [
    {
      "id": 1, "image":"https://path/to/my/image/1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2, "image":"https://path/to/my/image/2.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using the json in a javascript function, and need to manipulate it to remove the root key. i.e. I want something that looks like

```
[
  {
    "id": 1, "image":"https://path/to/my/image/1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2, "image":"https://path/to/my/image/2.jpg"
  }
]
```

I've been hacking around with various approaches, and have referred to several similar posts on SO, but nothing seems to work. The following seems like it should.

```
var url = 'http://path/to/my/json/feed.json';
var jsonSource = $.getJSON( url );
var jsonParsed = $.parseJSON(jsonSource);
var jsonFeed = jsonParsed.photos
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ Andy: Copy-and-paste is your friend. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of issues there.

1. That's invalid JSON, in two different ways. A) The `:` after `"photos"` means that it's a property initializer, but it's inside an array (`[...]`) when it should be inside an object (`{...}`). B) There are extra `"` characters in front of the `images` keys. So the first thing is to fix that.
2. You're trying to use the return value of `$.getJSON` as though it were a string containing the JSON text. But `$.getJSON` returns a `jqXHR` object. You need to give it a success callback. That callback will be called with an object graph, the JSON is automatically parsed for you.

Assuming the JSON is fixed to look like this:

```
{
    "photos": [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "image": "https://path/to/my/image/1.jpg"
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "image": "https://path/to/my/image/2.jpg"
      }
    ]
}
```

Then:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var photos = data.photos;

    // `photos` now refers to the array of photos
});
```

Comment: Thanks TJ, your answer makes sense, but I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in the console. How can I debug what is causing this?

Comment: @AndyHarvey: The error should tell you what code threw the error. It's either an error in the JSON (e.g., it doesn't really look like the above) or the code. The code above, with the JSON above, will work.

Comment: This is how you remove, but how do you add a root key?